# What is the difference between tar and zip?

Tags: unix, compression, zip, tar

What is the difference between tar and zip?  What are the use cases for each?

Comment: See these two answers from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/): - [Which is more efficient - tar or zip compression? What is the difference between tar and zip?](https://superuser.com/questions/173756/which-is-more-efficient-tar-or-zip-compression-what-is-the-difference-between) - [On Linux/Unix, does .tar.gz versus .zip matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/146754/on-linux-unix-does-tar-gz-versus-zip-matter) (By the way, StackOverflow is for programming problems. You'd probably do better asking questions like this at SuperUser in the future)

Answer (score 478, accepted):

`tar` in itself just bundles files together (the result is called a *tarball*), while `zip` applies compression as well.

Usually you use `gzip` along with `tar` to compress the resulting *tarball*, thus achieving similar results as with `zip`.

For reasonably large archives there are important differences though.  A `zip` archive is a *collection of compressed files*.  A gzipped tar is a *compressed collection* (of uncompressed files).  Thus a zip archive is a randomly accessible list of concatenated compressed items, and a `.tar.gz` is an archive that must be fully expanded before the catalog is accessible.

- The *caveat* of a `zip` is that you don't get compression across files (because each file is compressed independent of the others in the archive, the compression cannot take advantage of similarities among the contents of different files); the *advantage* is that you can access any of the files contained within by looking at only a specific (target file dependent) section of the archive (as the "catalog" of the collection is separate from the collection itself).
- The *caveat* of a `.tar.gz` is that you must decompress the whole archive to access files contained therein (as the files are within the tarball); the *advantage* is that the compression can take advantage of similarities among the files (as it compresses the whole tarball).

Comment: I'm a little confused. The last paragraph and the list seem to contradict each other. A `zip` compresses files into a catalog, but the caveat is that you **don't** get compression across files? Similarly for `.tar.gz`. Is there a typo in there?

Comment: @DillonRyanRedding Edited.  Does this resolve your confusion?

Comment: What do you mean with `tar.gz`you need to decompress the whole file to access files? I easily do `tar -f myfile.tr.gz -xzv file-that-i-want-to-extract.pdf` and it works.

Comment: @mariano-daniel A `.tar.gz` file is a gzip-ed tar file, which means tar will have to unzip the `.tar.gz` file (possibly in memory) to get to the contained (uncompressed) `.tar` file, which contains the file you want to ultimately extract.  To see, try: `gunzip myfile.tar.gz`; you will get the contained (uncompressed) `myfile.tar` file (NOTE: gunzip will delete the original `myfile.tar.gz` file, so you might want to make a backup copy first)

Comment: @Attila thanks for clarifying! So `tar` will have to unzip the file, not you ;-)  But seriously, now I understand what you meant, I took it too literally and thought you meant I needed to unzip it, then extract from the tar.  Have a nice day!